# Node.js POST request to Kohana

Tags: node.js, kohana

When I'm doing POST query by `node.js` filled with some data to `Kohana`, I always obtain in `$this->request->post()` empty array, but when I'm doing it by browser native `JavaScript` ajax call - it obtains proper data - which I've sent.

Node.js code (I'm using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library) - not working:

```
request.post(
    'http://someurl',
    { id : 'ididididid' },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('returned BODY:', body);
        }
    }
);
```

Node.js is obtaining response `(statusCode == 200)` but it's empty array

jQuery code - working well:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'http://someurl',
    dataType : 'JSON',
    data : {
        id : 'idididid'
    },
    done : function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);    
    }
});
```

Kohana code (inside controller):

```
$data = $this->request->post();
echo json_encode($data);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In Kohana, you don't use `$this->request->post` for the global `$_POST` var, that's intended for internal (sub) requests.

In your case, you'd do simply:

```
$this->response->body(json_encode($_POST));
```

Make sure you always assign the response to the body, since that's the correct way of doing it in Kohana

If you would to do:

```
Request::factory('/someurl')->post(array('id' => 'idididid'))->execute();
```

Then your `$this->request->post` would return the data